# Entity Framework inserting parent Id for navigation property Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class with a 1-0..1 relationship to another. The two are navigation properties of each other. The `Id` column should be filled by the DB, but EF 6 is trying to pass the `Id` of the parent as the Id of the child navigation property. I have no idea why this is happening. The specific error is `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tablename' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

When the actual `context.SaveChanges()` call is made, the `Id` of the navigation property is `0`, as it should be. I used SQL Server Profiler to check, and the INSERT statement to the DB is trying to insert the Id of the parent instead.

How can I fix this so EF doesn't try to use the Id of the parent as the new Id of the navigation property?

For purposes of this question, the parent and child can both be assumed to have only a column `Id` in the database, as well as `PurchaseOrderId` in the child table that points to the parent table (`PurchaseOrder`).

Parent class (`BaseEntity` contains the `Id` property):

```
public partial class PurchaseOrder : BaseEntity
{
    // misc properties
    public virtual AckException AckException { get; set; }
}
```

Child class:

```
public partial class AckException : BaseEntity
{
    // misc properties
    public virtual int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Nothing in the parent mapping (`PurchaseOrder`) references the child (`AckException`) in any way.

Child mapping:

```
public AckExceptionMap()
{
    ToTable("AckException");
    HasKey(c => c.Id);
    // misc properties
    Property(u => u.PurchaseOrderId).IsRequired();

    HasRequired(ex => ex.PurchaseOrder)
        .WithOptional(p => p.AckException);
}
```

The `PurchaseOrder` DB has no reference to `AckException`. `AckException` has a `PurchaseOrderId` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to specify the FK in AckException object, remove PurchaseOrderId from that object

Instead, you should do

```
HasRequired(ex=>ex.PurchaseOrder).WithOptional(p=>p.AckException).Map(a => a.MapKey("PurchaseOrderId"));
```

EF will automatically create a FK in the table

Comment: I have no idea why this works and my attempted solution doesn't, but this fixes it. (I've used my solution on several projects, never had an issue until now.) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your example (foreign key association vs above example independant association) you need to map your foreign key either in your model or in your fluent api.

1) Model:

```
[ForeignKey("PurchaseOrderId")
public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
```

2) Fluent api:

```
HasRequired(ex => ex.PurchaseOrder)
    .WithOptional(p => p.AckException)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PurchaseOrderId);
```